# Libgit2 global state and thread safety

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, libgit2

I'm trying to revise our codebase which seems to be using libgit2 wrong (at least TSAN is going crazy over how we use it).

I understand that most operations are object based (aka, operations on top of repo are localized to that repo), but I'm unclear when it comes to the global state and which operations need to be synchronized globally.

Is there a list of functions that require global synchronization?

Also when it comes to `git_repository_open()`, do I need to ensure that one path is only ever held by a single thread? I.e. do I need to prevent multiple threads accessing the same repo?